# Read from standard input and associate it with the following standard input

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double labor = 3;
  double squareFt = 160;
  double oneGallon;
  double chargePerHour = 28; //charger per hour for labor
  double numOfRooms; //input from user
  double sqFootage; //input from user 
  cout<<"Welcome to Artistic Solutions."<<endl;
  cout<<"Please enter the number of rooms that will be painted."<<endl;
  cin>>numOfRooms);
  cout<<"Please enter the squart footage of wall space in each room."<<endl;
  cin>>sqFootage);

  return 0;
}
```

This is a lab assignment in which it calculates how much a paint job will cost. It asks for how many rooms need to be painted and the square inch for EACH room. Is there a way to associate "numOfRooms" and "sqFootage"? What I want to do is minimize the repetition of asking the square footage of each room. Would the use of arrays and pointers help?

Comment: `cin>>sqFootage);` you will need a loop here (and one less ')') to read more than one room's square footage. Stop writing code and put together a list of things you need to do, a requirements document of sorts. Once you have that, figure out the order you need to accomplish the requirements in and then you'll have a much better idea on what you really need to do and hopefully have the beginnings of a plan of attack.

Comment: Think about how you can use loops and functions to minimize repetition.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need arrays, as you don't have to store the data.

You also can't really avoid repetition, because anyway the user will have to insert all the different values. However, you can save code and write it just once.

You can use a `for` loop to ask for `sqFootage` as much times as needed.

```
int sumSqFootage = 0, numOfRooms;
cout...
cin >> numOfRooms;
for (int i = 0; i < numOfRooms; i++)
{
    int sqFootage;
    cout...
    cin >> sqFootage;
    sumSqFootage += sqFootage;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. However, the program asks the user to input the number of rooms, so let's say the user inputs the number 4. I would have to ask  the user to enter the square footage 4 times, but I want to minimize that so as to not be so repetitive. Let me know if that clears some stuff up.

Comment: @user237448 Wait, each room has a different square footage?

Comment: Yeah, so I want to do this:1 sq footage - 1 Room, 2 sq footage - 2 Room and so on.

Comment: Oh I think I got it.

Comment: @user2373448 There is no need for code repetition, but repetition is an absolute must. You are going to have to ask for input more than once and compute more than once, but you can use the exact same code over and over.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help! I await when what I wish to happen will be able to happen!

Comment: What do you wish to happen?